# FFMPEG multiple file pattern not working in single command

Tags: ffmpeg, filepattern

I want to add multiple file sequences in single ffmpeg command, below is my code, video is getting created but only first image sequence is getting used, second is getting ignored

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -start_number 0000001 -i 1/%07d.png -i 2/%07d.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,0,3)'[v1];[v1][2]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,3.8561422222222,6.9761777777778)'[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a out.mp4
```

Now the problem is FFMPEG wants continous images, which i don't have i have images starting from `0000001.png` in each folder, how can i accomplish this without changing much in my images

Comment: @llogan can you help me with this?

Comment: How many images in 2nd sequence?

Comment: @Gyan there will be any number of images available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the glob pattern to deal with inconsistent numbering and pad the PTS with setpts so the overlay doesn't get consumed before it is displayed:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -pattern_type glob -i "1/*.png" -pattern_type glob -i "2/*.png" -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,0,3)'[v1];[2]setpts=PTS+3.856/TB[fg];[v1][fg]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,3.8561422222222,6.9761777777778)'[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a out.mp4
```

Comment: `PTS+3.856` --> `PTS+3.856/TB`

Answer (score 0):

Can you pipe the images to `-f image2pipe` ?

```
cat $(find 1 2 -name '*.png' -print) | ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 \
-f image2pipe -vcodec png -i - \    
-filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,0,3)'[v1];[v1][2]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,3.8561422222222,6.9761777777778)'[v2]" \
-map "[v2]" -map 0:a out.mp4
```

Comment: @l-scott-johnson `Invalid file index 2 in filtergraph description [0][1]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,0,3)'[v1];[v1][2]overlay=x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,3.8561422222222,6.9761777777778)'[v2]`

Comment: Try breaking it down (i.e., remove the maps, remove the filter_complex, remove the first input, etc. until you have a working piece, then build it back up.)