# FFMPEG 1 Audio + 1 Still image + multiple image frames at several times

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to create a video from combination of all these files which includes single audio file, still image in background and multiple image frames at several times, i have achieved this with video file on this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243250/ffmpeg-multiple-file-pattern-not-working-in-single-command) Now i have tried a failure attempt to create audio with same approach. But got an error which is obvious because still lack of knowledge in FFMPEG

Following is my failure attempt with error `Output with label 'v2' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.`

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i bg.jpg -i img/%07d.png -i dia.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest -vf "[0:v]scale=1280:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:1280[v1],[v1][2]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,6)'[v2]" -map "[v2]" out.mp4 2>&1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i bg.jpg -i img/%07d.png -i dia.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest -filter_complex  "[0:v]scale=1280:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:1280[v1];[v1][1]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,6)'" out.mp4 2>&1`

The pad numbering is wrong, and there should be a semi-colon after the bg image scale.

Comment: Now it receives error `was expected to have exactly 1 input and 1 output. However, it had >1 input(s) and 1 output(s). Please adjust, or use a complex filtergraph (-filter_complex) instead.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument`

Comment: @BhavikRathod Copy and paste Gyan's command, or use `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf` as shown in the answer and as described in your error message.